# How to change Apache Airflow Python path from Python 2.7 to 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, pythonpath

Initially, I had installed Apache Airflow and python 2.7 is set as default path. Now, I'm trying to change path from 2.7 to 3. Is it possible to do so or do I have re-install the airflow and set the python path? Any pointers would be helpful?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using any python virtual environment like this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html? Unless, I would suspect that your default python is used, which often is 2.7

Comment: No, I'm not using virtual environment for python3. Both are installed through Terminal, but not on virtual env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to make sure that you are using the version of Python that you would like. Docker is one, take a look at https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow for a good example.

Another is to use virtual environments. I've only used [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) with success. I like [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but unfortunately I ran into some dependency-trouble using it with Airflow.

Anyways, here is an example of what should work with Virtualenv:

```
cd your-project
virtualenv -p python3 .direnv
source .direnv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`python --version` should list python 3, and running `airflow webserver`, should run Airflow in python 3.

Answer (score 1):

> I had installed Apache Airflow and python 2.7 is set as default path.

Use

```
pip3 install apache-airflow
```

instead of

```
pip install apache-airflow
```